# bad encoding for xml

Tags: java, encoding

I have a string like this `" <person name="peter" ><\person>"`

URL encoding

```
URLEncoder.encode(person.toString(),"UTF-8");
```

but the encoding is bad because for spaces make `+` insted of `%20` and for `=` he gives other values can you guys help me?

Comment: Are you sure it is not the end tag?  It should be "</person>"

Comment: What's the problem exactly? It's a correct `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-type encoding (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: Why do you wnat to URL-encode this? Do you know what you are doing?

Comment: well actually i need to access a webservice that is not mine and the answer is these 
"%3Cperson+name%3D%22peter%22/%3E%3C/person%3E"

Comment: @Blazes It shouldn't matter here since it's just treated as a string.

Comment: @subspider So what you actually want is to URLDECODE this answer, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly as specified in the [`URLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) javaDoc. Space is converted to `+` and `=` is "unsafe" and thus encoded to `%3D`.

If you need a `%20` instead of the `+`, just do some post processing:

```
URLEncoder.encode(person.toString(),"UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
```

Comment: thanks for helping i was just wondering if there was other type of encoding

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment I assume you want to [decode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) the webservice answer.

```
// the answer you receive from the webservice
string webserviceResponse = "%3Cperson+name%3D%22peter%22%3E%3C%2Fperson%3E";

// turn into a "good" Xml string
string person = URLDecoder.decode(webserviceResponse, "UTF-8");
```

will give you

```
<person name="peter"></person>
```

as the value of `person`.

Comment: no the webservice does that a need to encode but even a simple `@` is transformed as `%40`

Comment: @subspider I didn't suggest the webservice does need to encode. From your comment above I assumed you actually want to decode the answer you receive from this external webservice.

Comment: @subspider Transforming special characters is the purpose of URLEncoding.